# Function to calculate distance

Tags: functions

sorry for the weird title but I don't really know how to put this ^^

I have 3 points like
[image: this]

I want to create a function that return a **positive value** if the red point is **close** to the **top point** and a **negative value** if the red point is **close** to the **bottom point**.
Furthermore, I want the distance to be a factor for the value returned (eg. if the top and bottom point are **close**, the value returned is **lowered**, if they are **far away** the value returned is **higher**)

I hope everything is clear, in any case feel free to ask ^^

Comment: Not clear which distance you care about for the factor. Is it blue to black?

Comment: Would this be a function of three variables (the three points)? And would the points be in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (have two coordinates), as shown? Would the points always be on the same vertical line? Do you want the value to be positive if the middle point is CLOSER to the top point than it is to the bottom point?

Comment: @Andrei it's both ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider
$$
(R - B) - (T - R) = 2R - B - T
$$
where $R, B, T$ stand for the $y$-coordinates of the red, bottom and top points.

If $R$ is between $B$ and $T$ this calculation gives a value between $B-T$ and $T-B$, so the distance between the top and the bottom is the maximum absolute value.

If $R$ is exactly midway between $B$ and $T$ the value will be $0$. If $R$ is at the top then the value will be $T-B$, so will be larger when the top and bottom are further apart.

If $R$ is allowed to be above $T$ or below $B$ you can decide whether this calculation still works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll check it out :)

Comment: It's working well !!! I will add a little something because I want higher values but the idea is there 